# iOS: Can you set up a ScrollView under IB?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can't seem to find a good tutorial for ScrollView so I've been trying to set it up myself using IB - is this even possible?

I've added a scrollview to a ViewController, sized it to 640x200, added a view at the same size with 2 labels at each end.  Created an outlet and linked it up to Files Owner, but when I run I see the first label but it won't scroll.  Basically I'm trying to create a half-height horizontal scroller to show a number of buttons, but I can't even get it moving.

Little help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve never managed to get desired results for the scroll view using IB. 
These two lines always do the trick:

```
   [mainScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 700)];
  [mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1200)];
```

Comment: Still not scrolling when I test it - probably missing something simple with the setup.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to set the `contentSize` in IB. So set it in `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller.

```
[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640,200)];
```